# To search contents of symlink

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, symlink

I want to search documents from by disc2 to which I created a symlink to disc1. 
However, I think this is not the way to go by creating a symblink to a current folder:

```
ln -s /Volumes/Disc2/books/Harrison_cd/pdf
```

because the files are not searchable by Finder, for instance.

I think mounting is an option but not sure here.

How can you search contents of symlink in Finder?

or

How would you mount contents to the location such that search works in that folder?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?
do you have an old path that doesn't exist ?
You mention Search -- how , with Spotlight or Grep or find or locate ?
-x

Comment: I updated the body of the question. Please, use `add a comment` next time for comments.